# How to handle big differences in data in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3 and I am learning how to make a bar chart.

My dataset has a huge range.

```
dataset = [12, 15, 60, 10000, 70000, 90000, 0.0002]
```

I am making a bar chart out of that dataset and it looks very weird. How do you deal with big difference in the dataset like that, so that the bar chart could look like it makes more sense? Because right now 0.0002 and 12 have the same size and that seems a bit odd.
I will appreciate any suggestion. Thank you in advance :)

Here is my code and the output:

```
<body>
  <script>
    const dataset = [12, 15, 60, 10000, 70000, 90000, 0.0002];
    
    const w = 500;
    const h = 300;
    const svg = d3.select("body")
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", w)
                  .attr("height", h);
    
    //create scale
    const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([d3.min(dataset), d3.max(dataset)])
        .range([10, 300]);
    
    //draw barchart
    svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
       .attr("y", 0)
       .attr("width", 25)
       .attr("height", (d, i) => {
         console.log(d,scale(d), scale(d)/d);
         return scale(d)
       });

        //add text labels
      svg.selectAll("text")
       .data(dataset)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 30)
       .attr("y", (d, i) => scale(d) + 15)
       .text((d, i) => d);

    // Add Axis
    const xAxis = d3.axisRight(scale);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w - 50) + ",0)")
      .call(xAxis);

  </script>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: See this answer to a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48109117/16363

Answer (score 1):

A logarithmic axis is what you need and d3 has one built in - https://d3js.org/d3-scale/log

Usability digression:

Some say they're harder to interpret than linear scales but the numbers we use in everyday life are base 10 logarithmic representations e.g. 4,000 is only 1 digit more than 400 which is only 1 digit more than 40 etc and people seem fine with those ;-)

It is true that cumulative charts are harder to read - https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/covid19/2020/05/19/the-public-doesnt-understand-logarithmic-graphs-often-used-to-portray-covid-19/ - but that's because people are trying to compare changes that will have different physical sizes dependent on where they occur on the scale

(Using a logarithmic scale when you don't need to is probably silly though)